# Use card columns without 'Masonry'-effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

**Goal**
A) Neat rows of cards, without the 'Masonry'-effect
B) Different amount of cards per row depending on screen size

I tried to solve the above by using `card-columns`, but I can't get it to work as I want it to (maybe `card columns` isn't the way to go?).

*A) I want...*
[image]

*A) I **don't** want...*
[image]

*B) The below code does work (i.e. it changes the number of cards per row), but I get the 'Masonry'-effect.*

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code to the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if the cards are **all the same height** (as shown in your image), the cards (using `card-columns`) are already "in neat rows": http://www.codeply.com/go/NyFi3vObhI

---

A better solution may be to use the **Bootstrap grid instead** of the card-columns. The `card-columns` are meant for masonry-like layout. The grid is responsive. For example, this...

`<div class="col-xl col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"></div>`

Will get you...

- **col-xl** = auto-width columns on xl
- **col-lg-3** = 4 columns on lg
- **col-md-4** = 3 columns on md
- **col-sm-6** = 2 columns on sm
- 1 column on xs is the default

http://www.codeply.com/go/DkPRDo4rPb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
           <div class="card card-block">
                <h2>Card</h2>
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card card-block">
                <h2>Card</h2>
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card card-block">
                <h2>Card</h2>
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card card-block">
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: If want want exactly 5 cols on `xl` widths, place a responsive div every 5 columns to force a "new line": `<div class="w-100 hidden-lg-down"></div>`

---

Another option maybe a [responsive card-deck](http://www.codeply.com/go/nIB6oSbv6q/bootstrap-responsive-card-deck).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It solves the 'Masonry'-issue, but the cards doesn't stick to its' size, it still seems a bit messy.

[image]

nb: I couldn't post the image as a comment => posted as answer.